# Алгоритм извлечения углов из матрицы вида и построение новой с сохранением ориентации

Tags: c++, opengl, матрицы, vulkan, glm

Я делаю приложение где пользователь может вращать камеру как орбит камеру. Только без ограничений. Пишу я на c++. Для математики использую библиотеку glm. Также пользователь может и взаимодействовать с координатами этой камеры. Собственно тут всё работает. Но я заметил что камера может вращаться очень много раз. И в результате вектор поворота может быть представлен как `{-2500, 650, 180}`. Причём я посмотрел подобное есть и во многих других 3D редакторах и никто с этим ничего не делает. Но я подумал что лучше всё таки стоит это всё выровнять.
Вращение осуществляется так:

```cpp
    mRotation = glm::rotate(mRotation, transform.rotation.y, glm::vec3(normalizedAxis, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    mRotation = glm::rotate(mRotation, transform.rotation.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, normalizedAxis, 0.0f));
    mRotation = glm::rotate(mRotation, transform.rotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, normalizedAxis));
mView = mTranslationMat * glm::mat4_cast(mRotation) * mTranslationCenter;
mViewInverse = glm::inverse(mView);
```

- `mRotation` - это квартерион вращения (мне нужно так, но поведение
  одинаково и в обычной `mat4`).
- `normalizedAxis` - позже отпишу.

Новые координаты вращения я извлекаю из матрицы вида используя следующую функцию:

```cpp
    float x, y, z;
    glm::extractEulerAngleXYZ(mView, x, y, z);
    if (transform.rotation.x < -glm::half_pi<float>() || transform.rotation.x > glm::half_pi<float>()) { // Значения нужно обратить если сменилась ориентация
        x = -x;
        y = -y;
    }
    transform.rotation = { y, x, z };
```

Функция вызывается при отжатии кнопки вращения (т.е. не в процессе, а после). И оно работает. При достижении 90° по оси x, к примеру, исходные координаты меняются (как и требовалось) и заменяются более оптимальными. Это вроде как в графике называется "вращение квартериона", если не ошибаюсь. Вот только когда это происходит конечная матрица вида выходит инвертированной по оси z. Т.е. мы смотрели спереди. Данные обновились и теперь вид сзади. Я в принципе понимаю почему. Я же меняю по факту только вращение не меняя квартерион трансляции. При этом кстати, если я открою blender, создам 2 камеры - одну с оригинальными координатами, другую с извлечёнными, эти камеры будут идентичным (в смысле находится в одной и той же точке, и смотреть в одну и другую точку). Наверное стоит привести пример:

Оригинальные:

```
X: -504.4 Y: -199.2 Z: -180
```

Извлеченные:

```
X: 35.6001 Y: 19.2001 Z: 0
```

Для решения этой проблемы я и ввёл переменную `normalizedAxis`. Теперь если произошло переворачивание то вращение мы будем нормализовать не к `1.0f`, а к `-1.0f`.

Я меняю код функции извлечения координат:

```cpp
    if (transform.rotation.x < -glm::half_pi<float>() || transform.rotation.x > glm::half_pi<float>()) {
        x = -x;
        y = -y;
        normalizedAxis = -1.0f;
    } else
        normalizedAxis = 1.0f;
```

Теперь ничего не переворачивается но другая проблема. Раз мы изменили `normalizedAxis`, то и вращение стало работать по другому. Теперь при вращении лево поворачивает направо, а право налево, к примеру. Я не придумал ничего лучше чем методом подбора добиться нужного результата:

```cpp
void Camera::rotate(float angleX, float angleY)
{
    auto v = std::round(transform.rotation.z / 0.00001f) * 0.00001f;
    angleX = up().y > 0.0f ? angleX : -angleX;
    if (v == 0.0f) {
        if (normalizedAxis == -1.0f) {
            angleX = -angleX;
            angleY = -angleY;
        }
    } else if (normalizedAxis == -1.0f && (transform.rotation.z < -glm::half_pi<float>() || transform.rotation.z > glm::half_pi<float>())) {
        angleY = -angleY;
    } else {
        angleX = -angleX;
    }
    transform.rotation.x += angleX;
    transform.rotation.y += angleY;
    ....
    ....
    ....
    /// Тут происходит вращение
}
```

Просто одна из вещей которая меня бесит в программировании - это делать много `if/else` когда не знаешь что делать. И я сделал также. Меня в принципе устраивает и этот результат, но я не могу не спросить. Есть решение лучше? Может быть есть какой-то алгоритм для сопоставления ориентации и выходных углов. Ну или просто совет :)

Comment: "квартерион трансляции" - что это?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну тут же как и в обычных матрицах. Есть вращение, трансляция и её центр. Вращение - чисто для вращения. Трансляция - для трансляции и зуминга. Ну если бы делалось матрицами, что для трансляции логичнее было бы объявить вектор `{center.x, center.y, eye.z}`

Comment: Вам не нужна сложная математика. Вычитайте из углов/прибавляйте к углам 360 пока не приведёте их в нужный диапазон.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy но в целом кстати да. Я думал об этом. И читал. Вроде так делают чтобы избежать gimbalLock. Но какой лок в камерах? Оно применимо только для объектов. Там просто выходят координаты не просто с `-n * 360.0f`, а именно "оптимальные". Т.е. более короткий маршрут по 3-м осям. Воспользуюсь тогда вашим советом